# Why can't I get the label to display text from the text field?

Tags: java, swing

I am currently making a News Ticker kind of program that scrolls the users inputted text accross the JLabel. Currently I can get it to display the text in a String Variable. However when I try to pass textual input into the field it cause's errors. What I have so far that works is the following;

```
public class Scroll2 extends JPanel implements Runnable, ActionListener{
JLabel label;
JLabel prompt;
JPanel LabelPan;
JPanel panelForText;
String str= "Hello";
String text;
JFrame mainFrame;
JTextField t;

public Scroll2(){
super();
mainFrame = new JFrame();
mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
mainFrame.setSize(new Dimension(840, 280));
mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
mainFrame.setVisible(true); 
mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

LabelPan = new JPanel();
LabelPan.isMaximumSizeSet();
LabelPan.setSize(620, 180);


label = new JLabel(str);
label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 70));

LabelPan.add(label);

panelForText = new JPanel();
panelForText.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));

prompt = new JLabel("Enter Text Here;");
panelForText.add(prompt);

t = new JTextField();
t.setSize(80, 53);
t.addActionListener(this);

panelForText.add(t);

mainFrame.add(LabelPan, BorderLayout.NORTH);
mainFrame.add(panelForText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

Thread t = new Thread(this);
t.start();
}

public void run(){

while(true){        
    char c = str.charAt(0);
    String rest = str.substring(1);
    str = rest + c;
    label.setText(str);      
    try{
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){}
}
}
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    JTextField t = (JTextField) evt.getSource();    


}
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scroll2 TextScroll = new Scroll2();
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Not an actual solution, but `Thread t = new Thread(this); t.start();` isn't smart.  Those action won't execute on the EDT, and therefore aren't thread safe.  Use a SwingTimer.

Comment: There is no any problem with your code.

Comment: The Label only displays the String that's preset with "hello". If I try and change the while loop to contain input text stored in the String text variable it brings back errors.

Answer (score 3):

You never bother to update `str` in your `actionPerformed()` method:

```
   public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent evt )
   {
//      JTextField t = (JTextField) evt.getSource();
      str = t.getText();
   }
```

Seriously if you took one minute to look at your code, you could have found this.  Maybe proper indenting would help you read your code better.

(I'm going to ignore the multi-threading errors in the code.  Read up on Swing concurrency: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/ )

Comment: Jesus, I can't believe I missed that... Thank you so much and I will :)